# Available TCP Port Probe with C#

Tags: c#

How can I probe an available TCP Port in order to programmatically configure WCF Service EndPoint ?

Answer (score 3):

How your client will know about the endpoint, if you dynamically choose your server port?

Anyway,

Here is a dirty way of probing for an open port

```
 for (int port = 2000; port < 65535; port++) 
                   {
                   IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                   Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, st, pt);

                   try { 
                         socket.Bind(ep);
                         socket.Close();  
                         //Port available
                        } 
                   catch (SocketException)
                        {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Port not available {0}", port);
                        } 

                   }
```

And then, try creating custom service host..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not a particularly elegant way, but you can just try opening the host and catch `AddressAlreadyInUseException` exceptions. That eliminates the use of `Socket` and the race condition that is present in amazedsaint's method: nothing can occupy the port between the check and your attempt to open the service.

So, basically:

```
ServiceHost host;

for(int port = 2000; port < 65535; port++) {
    var address = GetBaseAddress(port);
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), address);
    try {
        host.Open();
        break;
    }
    catch(AddressAlreadyInUseException) {

    }
}
```

The `GetBaseAddress` method just creates an address with `String.Format` to put the port number in the right place in your address pattern.

I suppose it's more relevant now seeing as we have [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:  [`Socket.Select`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?